# How to get Add To Calendar Button Package working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use [this component](https://github.com/jekuer/add-to-calendar-button) in my app.
I felt like it was straight forward, but I am encountering a `TypeError` from within the package.

I am building the following react component:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { atcb_init } from 'add-to-calendar-button';
import './addToCalendar.css';

export const AddToCalendar = (props: any) => {

  useEffect(() => atcb_init());

  return (
      <div className='atcb'>
          <script type="application/ld+json">
              {JSON.stringify(props)}
          </script>
      </div>
  );
}
```

and I am using the component on my `App.tsx` like this  `<AddToCalendar event={BookingEvent}/>`. The structure of Booking event is as follows:

```
 const BookingEvent = {
        name: "Add the title of your event",
        startDate: "2022-04-21",
        endDate: "2022-04-22",
        options:[
            "Google"
        ]
    }
```

this is throwing an

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
at atcb_clean_schema_json (index.js:69:1
```

I've tried stepping through the package and I can't figure out why this is not working, I thought I was following the instructions in the documentation correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the date - should work without time and then default to a full-day event.

**The problem is the JSON structure.**
Since the schema.org mode is used here, the structure is expected to have the event core data wrapped in an event block.
The following should work:

```
const BookingEvent = {
  event: {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    name: "Add the title of your event",
    startDate: "2022-04-21",
    endDate: "2022-04-22"
  },
  options:[
    "Google"
  ]
}
```

You could also (alternatively), adjust the wrapping html to go for the non-schema way.

```
return (
  <div className='atcb' style={{display: 'none'}}>
    {JSON.stringify(props)}
  </div>
);
```

***BTW: I hardly recommend to set a timezone!!***

I will add some more error handling to the code and optimize documentation (I see the missunderstanding here).

And there will even be a v1.7 with better React support. You can try the still not ready dev branch, if you want to: https://github.com/jekuer/add-to-calendar-button/tree/v1.7.0_dev

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass a valid date time like  `startDate: "2022-02-21T10:13"`